# i just tried to rebuild the project

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
    is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
    Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
    AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 1s ┌─ Flutter Fix
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │ [!] Your project requires a higher compileSdkVersion.
> │ │ Fix this issue by bumping the compileSdkVersion in
> G:\TOKU\android\app\build.gradle: │ │ android {
> │ │   compileSdkVersion 31
> │ │ }
> │
> └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 Exited
> (sigterm)

i deleted the project and open it again
then , everytime i try run the project this massage is appering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your compileSdkVersion 33.